# Using Discovery with a WCF Client to determine endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

The following code works on my server machine:

```
  var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
  var findCriteria = FindCriteria.CreateMetadataExchangeEndpointCriteria(typeof(DevExpress.Xpo.DB.IDataStoreService));
  findCriteria.MaxResults = 1;
  var findResults = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);

  foreach (EndpointDiscoveryMetadata item in findResults.Endpoints)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("uri found = " + item.Address.Uri.ToString());
    List<Uri> uris = new List<Uri>(item.ListenUris);
    var endpoints = MetadataResolver.Resolve(typeof(DevExpress.Xpo.DB.IDataStoreService), item.Address);

  }

  if (findResults.Endpoints.Count > 0)
  {
    var endpoints = MetadataResolver.Resolve(typeof(DevExpress.Xpo.DB.IDataStoreService), findResults.Endpoints[0].Address);
    if (endpoints.Count > 0)
    {
      foreach (var item in endpoints)
      {
        if (item.Name.Contains("NetTcpBinding"))
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Discovered NetTcpAddress [{0}]", item.Address);
          tcpEndpoint = item.Address;
        }
        if (item.Name.Contains("BasicHttpBinding"))
          basicHTTPendpoint = item.Address;
      }
    }

  }
```

There are two foreach loops only as part of my tries to get this working.

When I try to use this on the client machine, the following exception is thrown when the code tries to execute the MetadataResolver method...

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Metadata contains a refer
ence that cannot be resolved: 'http://192.168.0.2:8112/mex'. ---> System.Service

    Model.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://192.1
    68.0.2:8112/mex that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorr
    ect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --
    -> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.N
    et.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected pa
    rty did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection fa
    iled because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.2:8112
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddre
    ss socketAddress)
       at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Sock
    et s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state,
    IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStre
    am()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

    Server stack trace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStre
    am()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpC
    hannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeS
    pan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
    eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
    eout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
    Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

    Exception rethrown at [0]:
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
    Msg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
    ta, Int32 type)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.IMetadataExchange.Get(Message request)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataReferenceRe
    triever.DownloadMetadata(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.R
    etrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.R
    etrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.ResolveNext(Resolve
    CallState resolveCallState)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(Metadat
    aRetriever retriever)
       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataResolver.Resolve(IEnumerable`1 con
    tracts, EndpointAddress address, MetadataExchangeClient client)
       at StandaloneClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\My Projects\AllTestType
    Progys\WCFTestLibrary\StandaloneClient\Program.cs:line 35
```

It finds the mex address OK but I need to ascertain which endpoint is using net.tcp and which endpoint is using http.

Comment: Couldn't see the tree in the woods - Windows Firewall was blocking it :-(